# Formato para tipo de datos DATE

Tags: java, sql, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, jdbc

Tengo una tabla en Spreadsheet de Google, con una columna "fecha" en la que recojo la fecha así: 2019-11-17

El caso es que quiero almacenar los datos de esa columna en mi bd de Cloud SQL, en la cual he creado una tabla con una columna "fecha" y tipo de datos "DATE". Sin embargo, cuando ejecuto el script para que me almacene estos datos me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error:

[image: Mensaje de error al ejecutar script]

La función que utilizo para guardar los datos en bd es la siguiente:

```
function escribir_datos() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
  conn.setAutoCommit(false);

  var valor = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("A3").getValue(); //celda 1
  var valor_2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("B3").getValue(); //celda 2
  var valor_3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("C3").getValue(); //celda 3
  var valor_4 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("D3").getValue(); //celda 4
  var valor_5 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("E3").getValue(); //ESTA ES LA CELDA DE LA FECHA

  var start = new Date();
  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO blog_amp '
      + '(sesiones_mobile_blog, sesiones_mobile_blog_yoy, sesiones_amp, sesiones_no_amp, fecha) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    stmt.setString(1, valor);
    stmt.setString(2, valor_2);
    stmt.setString(3, valor_3);
    stmt.setString(4, valor_4);
    stmt.setString(5, valor_5);
    stmt.addBatch();
  }

  var batch = stmt.executeBatch();
  conn.commit();
  conn.close();

  var end = new Date();
  Logger.log('Registrando en BD');
}
```

¿Alguna idea para almacenar la fecha?

Parece que aunque en Spreadsheet la celda tenga el forma fecha, el dato real que recoge el script lo hace con otro formato (el de la imagen)

Comment: Has probado a importar Date como `java.sql.Date` en vez de como `java.util.Date` y hacer `stmt.setDate(5, start);` ?

Comment: Al igual que el código, los mensajes de error deben colocarse como texto, no como imagen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al leer una celda de una **hoja de cálculo de Google** que contiene una fecha, **Google Apps Script** devuelve un objeto de **JavaScript** tipo "Date". El valor que ves reflejado en el mensaje de error ocurre porque cuando se parsea un objeto tipo "Date" como "String" devuelve la fecha en el formato mostrado, en este caso `Sun Nov 11 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)`

En Google Apps Script puedes usar `Utilities.formatDate(date,timezone,format)` para generar un "String" que tenga el formato de fecha que requieras.

Referencias

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format

Comment: Perfecto, ahora sí que he podido, gracias!!